# What is a fast, universal way to launch a particular app (from within any other app)?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I want a seamless way to launch a particular app at any moment on iOS, whether the device is locked, on the home screen or in a particular app.

Is there any way to create any kind of shortcut or functionality to do so?

Of course, simply going to the home screen and then clicking on the app is possible, but my desire is to give the ability to launch the app even more directly, without any intermediate steps.

I may be able to make an Apple Shortcut that launches the app, but it would only be accessible if there were a Share menu in the app I was in.

I think I could make a Siri shortcut, but it would have to be voice activated, and that’s not ideal for all situations.

So: is there any hack or possibility I haven’t thought about for quickly launching a specific app, from anywhere?

Right now, the only idea I have is being able to associate launching a Shortcut with a particular hardware functionality like tapping the back of the phone, clicking the power button and volume button at the same time, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the hardware functionality you mention in the last paragraph of your question, I think the only other solution is to use the NFC support in Shortcuts like this:

Open up the Shortcuts app and tap the Automatics tab in the bottom of the screen. Tap the "Create Personal Automation" button and then choose "NFC". Tap the "Scan" button and hold the NFC tag on to the phone. Then tap "Next" and "Add Action" and choose the app functionality to launch.

Now you can use the tag to trigger the launch at any moment.

NOTE: You need an iPhone XS or later that supports background tag reading.

Answer (score 1):

There is "Back Tap" accessibility feature in iOS 14 which can be used. It allows to perform various system actions by tapping on the rear of the device.

When the back of iPhone is tapped, an action will be carried out. This includes launching many of the system actions but also launching shortcuts.

Start with creating shortcut to open specific app. Then head to Accessibility > Touch > Back Tap (last choice). Assign double (or triple) tap to shortcut created. Thats it. Now, whenever you double tap on back of your iPhone this app opens.